# Android: Possible to have a seperate Java file for each Activity?

Tags: java, android, file, android-activity

Greetings,

I'm currently developing an Android application, but I'd like to be able to handle button click events etc in a separate file for each Activity. Is this possible? At the moment, I have one very large file that handles all events for several Activity windows.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For event handling there is OnClickListener interface, you can create your own implementation and use it only in place you get the button, for example in onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
  ...
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick() {
       // the code
     }

}
```

So, you don't have to create a separate file at all.

Comment: Thanks for the message. Ok, so I should handle all events for the entire app in one file? Is that standard practice?

Comment: Events happening to the entire activity should be handled inside that activity. Activity is supposed to be you UI controller. But don't forget: if you have a lot of business logic in your onClickListener, then you should consider the moving of it to another place class and just call this code from your onClickListener().

Comment: Hi Vladimir, that makes sense now. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible (at least in a clean way).

To handle a click, you must implement one interface (View.OnCLickListener). I'm assuming clicking in a different view will produce a different type of response (i.e. one button might open a popup and another might start an activity).

Yes, you could check the id of the view that was clicked and decide what to do based on that.. but this looks like ugly!

In order to accomplish code reuse, usually I implement everything in a inner class. This way I can choose what to do in each case just once.

If you've done something very general, you might do it in a separate file so you can reuse it in other classes.

Comment: Ok, well that clears things up for me. I'll just keep going the way I'm going and try and user inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should spend a little time familiarizing yourself with the basics of object orientation before you go further - you are doing yourself a disservice because without the basic understanding, you are probably going to write a ton of code that in the end, wouldn't be needed if you had the basic understanding.  Pick up a beginning Java book or do a tutorial or two online - you will be glad you did.

And I hope you don't take my advice to be picking on you - I am simply telling you that your question indicates you don't know the basics.

Now to answer your question...  You want to create a single class that implements all the shared event handling logic (shared code means only the code that ***all*** activities will use).  You will then use this shared event handler from each of your Activity classes by making your activity classes either an **IS A** EventHandlingClass or **HAS A** EventHandlingClass.  Now its up to you to find out what **IS A** or **HAS A** actually means, and when you do, you will then have the basic understanding of object oriented languages.

Good Luck!

Rodney